# MERN unit test fails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, unit-testing, mern

I am trying to develop a MERN application. But MERN POST method unit testing fails with following error

ERROR:

1 failing

1. POST /product/save/
   OK, creating a new product works:
   AssertionError: expected { error: { errors: { …(5) }, …(3) } } to have property '_id'
   at Context. (test/api/product/post.js:33:29)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5

I have attached the code below.

MERNProject/products.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  productName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  productCategory: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  productUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Products", postSchema);
```

MERNProject/routes/products.js

```
    const express = require("express");
const Products = require("../models/products");

const router = express();

//save Products
router.post("/product/save", (req, res) => {
  let newProduct = new Products(req.body);

  newProduct.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err,
      });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: "Product saved successfuly",
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

MERNProject/test/api/post.js

```
   const expect = require("chai").expect;
    const request = require("supertest");
    
    const app = require("../../../routes/products.js");
    const conn = require("../../../server.js");
    
    describe("POST /product/save/", () => {
      before((done) => {
        conn
          .connect()
          .then(() => done())
          .catch((err) => done(err));
      });
    
      after((done) => {
        conn
          .close()
          .then(() => done())
          .catch((err) => done(err));
      });
    
      it("OK, creating a new product works", async () => {
        const res = await request(app).post("/product/save/").send({
          productName: "Mango",
          description: "description Mango",
          price: "rs 50",
          productCategory: "fruits",
          productUrl:
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/Hapus_Mango.jpg",
        });
    
        const body = res.body;
        expect(body).to.contain.property("_id");
        expect(body).to.contain.property("productName");
        expect(body).to.contain.property("description");
        expect(body).to.contain.property("price");
        expect(body).to.contain.property("productCategory");
        expect(body).to.contain.property("productUrl");
      });
    });
```

MERNProject/server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

//import routes
const postRoutes = require("./routes/products");

//app middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(postRoutes);

const PORT = 8000;
const DB_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://twg:twg123@cluster0.ong7q.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

function connect() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose
      .connect(DB_URL)
      .then((res, err) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        //console.log(`DB connected`);
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(`DB connection error`, err));
  });
}

function close() {
  return mongoose.disconnect();
}

connect();

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App is running on ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = { connect, close };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an error returned by your post request and the `body` contains an error instead of the object you expect. From the traces, it seems to be something like:

> { error: { errors: { …(5) }, …(3) } }

I would say that your test works fine, the assertion raised an error and the test failed :)

To investigate further, you should log the content of `res`

Comment: it shows like this error: {
      errors: [Object],
      _message: 'Products validation failed',
      name: 'ValidationError',
      message: 'Products validation failed: productUrl: Path `productUrl` is required., productCategory: Path `productCategory` is required., price: Path `price` is required., description: Path `description` is required., productName: Path `productName` is required.'
    }
  },

Comment: I can only guess but I would say that either your backend or your database is refusing the input data of the product you are trying to add to the DB. You should check the content of the data passed to the POST request

Comment: The request body sets as undefined when doing the testing.